# CocoaPods M1 doesn't generate .xcworkspace file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I installed CocoaPods and go to the directory of my project. First I use "pod init" command and edit the Podfile, adding my pods. After that when I use "pod install" command, it doesn't generate any .xcworkspace file and doesn't install any pods at all.

I already downloaded XCode Command Line tools and activated them from the Preferences -> Locations tab. I uninstalled and install CocoaPods. I used Homebrew and try to run the terminal using Rosetta but none of them worked.

I don't receive any error at all. It only creates .xcworkspace file when I use "pod init" and "pod install" commands one after another without touching Podfile. After that when I edit the Podfile and run command, it doesn't load any pods. Can someone help me please because I'm stuck.

Comment: You first say "I installed CocoaPods".  You then say you've created a pod file with 'pod init.'  Next, you suggest that you've entered 'pod install' in the Terminal window.  So what do you mean by your very first statement, saying you've installed Cocoapods?  And when you type 'pod install' and press RETURN, what happens?  Did you close the Terminal window without having pods installed?

Comment: Oh, I get it.  You first typed 'sudo gem install cocoapods' in the Terminal window to install cocoapods.